# What happens when you heat 5 cubic meters of iron to 3500k in 0.1 seconds?

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, estimation

I've been googling this problem all night. I have no relevant degrees in physics, but I'm fascinated by it.

In the Warhammer 40.000 universe there is a portable weapon called a "melta" it is fx used in boarding actions on space ships.

The basic idea is that the target area is heated suddenly and violently, instantly vaporizing metals. I'm thinking this might have some dire real-world consequences that the authors didn't think of and I want to know exactly how bad it's gonna go.

So assuming and ambient pressure of 1 atmosphere and 20C or 293K and you heat 5 cubic meters of iron to 3500 degrees kelvin in 0.1 seconds, what will happen? Does the iron expand? If so how much? In case it creates a mechanical shockwave (as explosions do), is it possible to calculate that too?

What would be your thoughts on using a weapon like this in the confines of a space ship?

As stated I'd very much like to math out this problem, but I have no clue where to begin.

Comment: I’ve nominated this to be reopened. I don’t see an engineering problem here. The question, dropping the science fiction fluff, is a physics question: what happens to a material and its surroundings when heated very quickly.

Comment: How would one go about carrying out this heating, assuming the iron is not all spread out into a very thin film initially?

Comment: It is not uncommon for Warhammer 40.000 authors to make ridiculous claims in order to make story seem epic and grand, without considering the consequences. There is fx this giant space marine dude running around in power armour made from neutron star material. Not a fine laquer or finish, but actually made from...